# "numberFormat" is not a function, mas ela é

Tags: javascript

Senhores,

A situação é a seguinte. Consegui uma função para formatar números para formatos financeiros. Ao aplicar, diz que não é uma função. Mas ela é.

Como proceder?

```
<script>

    // * Função para formatar em formato de dinheiro
    Number.prototype.numberFormat = function(n, x, s, c) {
        var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + (x || 3) + '})+' + (n > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')',
            num = this.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~n));

        return (c ? num.replace('.', c) : num).replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&' + (s || ','));
    };




    // * Aqui que vou utiliza-la
    $(function(){

        ...

        // * Função que busca o plano mais adequado no BD
        function atualizaPlano(disco, ram, cpu, os){

            $.ajax({

                ...

                // * Caso retorne
                success:function(produto){

                    valorProduto = produto[0]['proValor'];
                    valorProduto = valorProduto.numberFormat(2, 3, '.', ',');

                    ...

                },

                ...

            });

        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Qual a saída de `console.log(typeof valorProduto )`?

Comment: Provavelmente ```valorProduto``` está como ```string```, e ```numberFormat``` só existe para números

Comment: @ArturoTemplário provavelmente era isso mesmo... forcei com parseFloat e deu certo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimenta:

```
valorProduto = parseFloat(produto[0]['proValor']);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo. Tenho que forçar o type do negócio então quando for utilizar sempre...